# Will Duke Nukem Forever support LAN games?

Tags: pc, duke-nukem-forever

Does anyone have information about this? I really hope this feature will be included in the game.

Comment: according to this the [last post of this thread](http://forums.gearboxsoftware.com/showpost.php?p=2364780&postcount=15) it will have LAN support... but not offline LAN support :/ Not sure if that's correct, no not posting it as an answer

Comment: Yes, but only via IPX ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a lot of fuss about this,people wanted LAN support and complained to gearbox on  their forums,there were also some petitions started.Rumors started that they will listen to public and add **offline LAN** support,but still after almost 3 years it wasn't implemented.

Most likely since game developers nowdays are skeptical about offline LAN,because they think more people will buy the game instead of bothering with pirated versions.Guess they were wrong since you can play pirated multiplayer on Tunngle.

They do however support **online LAN**,meaning you need to join your steam community account and then you can join local servers.

And they did add the **dedicated server** tools,so if you know your way with servers you can get it to work in LAN.